# How to find number of total consumers/listener on remote ActiveMQ queue

Tags: java

I have one queue I.e. `FastAutomationBus`. Now I want to find out how many consures/listerner are listening msg in that queue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [consumer advisories](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) . Advisory messages can be thought as some kind of administrative channel where you receive information regarding what is happening on your JMS provider along with what's happening with producers, consumers and destinations.

You can also use [JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) to monitor and control the behaviour of the broker.

Answer (score 0):

You can find same in AMQ Management console, there is a tab called Consumers, where it lists all listeners tagged to a particular queue/topic.
You can find IP address and creation time of listener.